# can sign derived wallet transactions with master seed phrase private key?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, mnemonic-seed

I would like to sign a transaction from a wallet which is derived from a seed, and sign it with master seed private key, can I sign any tx of any derived wallet address after the master seed wallet?

thanks a lot.

Comment: No you need to derive a private key from the master in order to sign a transaction (which, I assume pays to the PKH of this key).

Comment: yeah, thanks for the response I'm a little confused, because I don't know if there a master seed than can sign any child wallet tx, instead of using its derived private key, it's like a father which signs all child's tx without prompting them.

Comment: No, there is not.

Comment: ok, both thanks a lot, I thought it was possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

The master private key is derived from the seed and all child private keys are derived from the master private key. Knowledge of the child private keys lets you sign transaction spending coins sent to the corresponding addresses. So yes if you have the master private key you can derive the child private keys and use those to sign any transactions related to that wallet.

Comment: ok, thanks for the response, I have a 12 word seed phrase, but I don't know how to do it using javascript there any any guide that you can share me, thanks a lot :)

Comment: what I meant was I have 12 word seed phrase, and it will generate a master private key, and I want to have another derived wallet using the same seed, then with with the second wallet send a tx no signed with its own derived private key  instead I will sign it using master private key can I do that? if so there any guide or link for explaining using any programming language. thanks a lot

Comment: @andrew007 master private key can't be used to sign transactions. also do learn the difference between a wallet and an address. a wallet contains many addresses. bitcoins are sent to addresses and spending transactions are signed with child private keys corresponding to those addresses.